# Implement File Upload like Dropbox by Appcelerator

Tags: file, upload, titanium, appcelerator, dropbox

I want to implement File Upload function like Dropbox. I use Appcelerator. This function can upload file from Acrobat, iBook, Work, Excel, Drive etc. And make in on iOS.

I have researched on Appcelerator but could not find any solution for this.

I dont know how to access to local storage on iOS or working with another app by Appcelerator.

Can you give me any suggestion about this problem

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should register `CFBundleDocumentTypes` in your `tiapp.xml` `ios` element, which works the same as modifying the `Info.plist` in Xcode would for an Obj-C or Swift app.  Once you have that completed, you can listen for the `resume` event in your app, and look at `Ti.App.getArguments()` to see if your app was launched by choosing "Open In" from another app. You can also look at the folder `Inbox` inside of `Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory` to see if there are any new files in there -- that's where iOS will place them when sharing them to your app.

Your code for handling the document could look like this (in your `resume` handler):

```
var cmd = Ti.App.getArguments(),
    inboxFiles = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'Inbox').getDirectoryListing() || [];
if (inboxFiles.length > 0) {
    inboxFiles = inboxFiles.sort(byLastCreated).map(toTiFile);
    if (!cmd.url) {
        cmd.url = inboxFiles[0].getNativePath();
    }
    if (inboxFiles.length > 1) {
        for (var i = inboxFiles.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            inboxFiles[i].deleteFile();
        }
    }
}
if (cmd && cmd.url && cmd.url.indexOf('file://') === 0) {
    // TODO: Do something interesting with cmd.url.
}
```